# Is there proper way to alias type depending on passed template value argument at compile time (c++)

Tags: c++, c++17

I wanna alias type according to passed template argument.
Depending on Passed Template argument int value, return Type is decided.
but there is many types what I want.
I wanna do this with clean code.

I know I can do this with `std::conditional_t`, but it's really messy. I need aliasing many types from int value

```
template <int value>
std::conditional_t<value== 1, Type1, std::conditional_t<value== 2, Type2, std::conditional_t<value== 3, Type3, Type4>>> Function()
{

}
```

but I wanna more clean ways.
Actually if I just put type at return type, I can do this, but I wanna use template value argument.

I don't know what should I use for this.

```
switch(value)
{
   case 1:
   using type = typename Type1;
   break;

   case 2:
   using type = typename Type2
   break;

}
```

I know this code is ill-formed, but this concept is what I want.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is the original problem such a template function is supposed to solve? How are you supposed to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't see a way to get a switch statement for declaring a `using` type.

The best I can imagine pass through a struct template specialization

```
template <int>
struct my_type;

template <> struct my_type<1> { using type = Type1; };
template <> struct my_type<2> { using type = Type2; };
template <> struct my_type<3> { using type = Type3; };

template <int value>
using my_type_t = typename my_type<value>::type;

template <int value>
my_type_t<value> Function ()
 {
   // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tuple:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t N>
using FunctionRetType = std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<
    /*0*/int,
    /*1*/bool,
    /*2*/float>>;
```

Applied:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr FunctionRetType<N> Function() { return 0; }

#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(Function<1>()), bool>);
}
```

And you can always add arithmetic on the `N` argument, for instance to realize 1-based indexing.

Comment: `std::tuple_element_t` is a nice alternative to a custom specialized type if the "key" in the "key-type" type map is `std::size_t`. Note however that you 1) do not need `typename` in the alias templates (this is the essence of the `_t` alias templates introduced in C++14) and 2) you would typically follow the STL idioms and similarly name the alias template with a trailing `_t`, renaming `type` to `type_t`.

Comment: @dfrib sorry, based it on some old example. And I think `type_t` would look quite odd...

Comment: @dfrib actually thinking about it. "you would typically follow the STL idioms and similarly name the alias template with a trailing _t, renaming type to type_t." that's a coding guideline. Not a general rule/guideline.

Comment: `myFunc` is not needed, as OP need mapping between N and T.

Comment: @Jarod42 true, just wanted to give a compete working example. The main is also not needed.